# How to resume CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I can successfully stop timer by using cancel() (timer.cancel()) function. But how to resume it? I searched a lot for various codes but everything was in Java. I need it in Kotlin. Can you give me suggestions? I use code:

```
val timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
            println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {}
    }
```

Edited:

In Class:

```
var currentMillis: Long = 0 // <-- keep millisUntilFinished

    // First creation of your timer
    var timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            currentMillis = millisUntilFinished // <-- save value

            textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
            println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {}
    }
```

In onCreate():

```
  timer.start()

            TextView2.setOnClickListener {
                //Handle click
                timer.cancel()

            }

            TextView3.setOnClickListener {
                //Handle click
                timer = object : CountDownTimer(currentMillis, 1000) {
                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        currentMillis = millisUntilFinished
                        textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
                        println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {}
                }
            timer.start()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion : keep the `millisUntilFinished` value and use it for recreating `CountDownTimer`

```
var currentMillis: Long // <-- keep millisUntilFinished

// First creation of your timer
var timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
   override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

     currentMillis = millisUntilFinished // <-- save value

     textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
     println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
   }

   override fun onFinish() {}
   }
}

...

// You start it
timer.start()

...

// For some reasons in your app you pause (really cancel) it
timer.cancel()

...

// And for reasuming
timer = object : CountDownTimer(currentMillis, 1000) {
   override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
     currentMillis = millisUntilFinished
     textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
     println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
   }

   override fun onFinish() {}
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer, resuming works but if I pause and resume, I can't pause again. I didn't figure out how to pause it again. Look at my edited code.

Comment: Oh sorry ! Reuse the same instance of ```timer``` for resuming. Remove ```var``` keyword before. I've edited my answer at the end

Comment: Thanks, it works now. However, it doesn't work very well. I noticed that if, for example, timer shows "6" and I press "cancel" button at the moment when it's almost "5", "cancel" button stops working sometimes.

Comment: If I cancel timer in `onPause()` and resume in 'onResume' timer still works in background. Do you know why?

Comment: I noticed it too ! But I don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

its been more than a year
i just started learning Kotlin
I could get pause and resume functionality successfully but there is a big lag in calling onFinish function
i am not recreating the timer object, on clicking a button i call timer.cancel() and set a flag to true
on clicking the button again, i check value of flag and if true i call timer.start() and set the flag to false