# How to disable depreciation in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, timer

I try to use function `formatNumber`but it's deprecated. How to disable depreciation? Or maybe use any alternative function?

[image]

Comment: Better fix that, there's always a reason why is deprecated, it means that the function may not work properly on some android versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should not disable the deprecation sign of a method. In most cases the given method's KDoc/Javadoc explains what should you use instead of the deprecated method.

**What does the deprecation means? (Offical Java docs)**

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are
>   discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because
>   a better alternative exists.

Although you can disable the deprecation sign 
with an annotation at method signature level:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun methodName() {
   ...
   deprecatedMethod()
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you explain me how to find alternative for `formatNumber`? How to search it? I tried on Google and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#formatting but didn't find this function.

Comment: Found:) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils#formatNumber(android.text.Editable,%20int)

Comment: I guess you are using the PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(String!) static method. Please, check it. 

If I am right, you should use formatNumber(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso) method.

Comment: It's difficult to understand because it isn't my code. I just downloaded it from github to figure out how to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944590/how-to-resume-countdowntimer I'm begginer in android programming

Comment: This github project https://github.com/MChehab94/Count-Down-Timer-Demo-Kotlin